# Biscuit burning around sides

Tags: burnt, biscuits

My biscuits are burning around the outside edge of the oven trays.
How can I stop this happening?

Comment: Can you let us know what kind of tray...what kind of oven...and at what temperature you are baking?

Comment: And what kind of biscuits? The word means different things to different people

Answer (score 3):

These are not perfect solutions, but merely hacks that could work.

- Make the outer biscuits slightly bigger to increase the cooking time needed.
- Let the inner biscuits cook for a few minutes, and then add the rest of the biscuits.
- Use aluminium foil to shield the outer biscuits from direct heat.